# Go to detail page in a React-Native Flatlist

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-flatlist

I made a Flatlist navigate to the detail screen when a row is clicked.

I created 4 files.

file1:

**index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import List from "./list";
import Detail from "./detail";
import { createStackNavigator, createAppContainer } from "react-navigation";

const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  ListScreen: {
    screen: List,
  },
  DetailScreen: {
    screen: Detail,
  },
}, {
    initialRouteName: 'ListScreen',
});

export default createAppContainer(AppNavigator);
```

And **detail.js**

```
export default class DetailScreen extends React.PureComponent  {
    render() {
      return (
        <View
          <Text>Home Details!</Text>
        </View>
      );
    }
}
```

**list.js**

```
    import Products from "./products";
    export default class ListScreen extends React.PureComponent  {
      ...

      renderItem({ item }) {
          return <Products product={item}/>
      }

      render() {
        return (

            <View style={{margin:5}}>
              <FlatList
                 data={this.state.products}
                 renderItem={this.renderItem}
                 keyExtractor={(item,index) => item.id.toString()}
              />
            </View>

        );
      }
```

And Finally

**products.js**

```
export default class ProductsType2 extends React.PureComponent {
  _onPress = () => {
    this.props.navigation.navigate('DetailScreen', this.props.product.id);
  };

  render() {
    const { product} = this.props;
    //const { navigate } = this.props.navigation; //get error w
    return (
      <Card>
          <CardItem cardBody button onPress={this._onPress}>
            <Image
              style={{height: 140, width: 140, flex: 1}}
              source={{uri: product.thumbnail}} />
          </CardItem>
        </Card>
      );
   }
}
```

when I press it I can't get the details screen to show up.

I get this error:

> Cannot read property 'navigate' of underfined

Comment: try replacing this.navigation.navigate with this.props.navigation.navigate

Comment: @Syed  I corrected it. I get same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use withNavigation (HOC) to access navigation props from products.js. That component not inside of the createStackNavigator, so export your class with `withNavigation` method and you can access the navigation props.

```
import { withNavigation } from 'react-navigation';

...

export default withNavigation(ProductsType2)
```

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/connecting-navigation-prop.html